# Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2 - Android Emulator requiring a swipe to display records

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2022, maui

Today, after creating a Blazor Project in the same VS Solution as a .Net Maui Project I began experiencing issues with the Maui app not compiling... missing Mac Catalyst Ref.  After a couple of failed attempts to correct the issue, I installed VS 2022 Preview 2.  This corrected the compiling issue but now when I run the app in the Android Emulator, 2 of the 3 forms need to be swiped for the Collections to display and the 3rd form is not a scrollable form and for that one I  modify the XAML to get the data to display.  I cold booted the Android Emulator and even rebooted Windows.. no luck.  The app worked in VS 2022 Preview 1 until I added the Blazor Project. It does work running it as a Windows App and unable to test IOS at this time.

Anyone else experiencing this?  In general, should I separate the two projects into their own Solutions?

Form 1, I must swipe in the white space for the records to appear, Form 2 blue space... Colleciton View with Horizontal Orientation.

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Please help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github link.

Comment: Alexandar, I created a project you can use to reproduce the issue minus SQL DB/Table and Web Service.  If you need these as well let me know.  To test this, point the Monkey Service to the GitHub Source GetMonkeys() which works.  Next point to a local Web Service (same machine) GetMonkeys2() and the CollectionView will not dispaly.  Based on this it appears to be a timining issue.  Adding a delay to the underlying proc of the local Web Webserivce corrected the issue in the Test App but not the Actual App.  

[link](https://github.com/ToddTaylorPL/AutoPopulatePage)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think the issue is related to the `Web Service`.You can try to survey in that direction.

Comment: Ok, root cause is related to the <ActivityIndicator>.  When I comment it out the collections populate as expected.  It was working previously so I will continue to investigate and post an answer if I correct the issue.